# Bilinear interpolation

Tags: functions, curves, interpolation

I need to find the coefficients $a_{jk}$ given the following equation:
$$ f(x,y)=\sum_{j,k=0}^Na_{jk}x^jy^k$$
in which are known $(N \times N)$ values of the function $f(x,y)$. What is the best method to find them?
In the case of $f(x)$, we can write:
$$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^Na_jx^j$$
so if we know N values of $f(x)$ we get the matrix equation:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
  f(x_1) \\
  f(x_2) \\
  \vdots  \  \\
  f(x_N) 
 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & x_1 & \cdots & x_1^N \\
  1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_2^N \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  1 & x_N & \cdots & x_N^N 
 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  a_0 \\
  a_1 \\
  \vdots  \  \\
  a_N 
 \end{pmatrix} $$
and inverting the coefficient matrix we can get the coefficient vector. How to get the coefficient matrix $a_{jk}$ in $2D$ case? Thanks.

Comment: This is not bilinear interpolation...

Comment: This looks like multivariate Lagrange interpolation. [This paper](https://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol1issue1/S01002.pdf) might be useful

Comment: Best method with respect to what? Do you want to implement this and have numerical errors in mind? Is it about speed or about finding a way at all?

Comment: @PaulAljabar, It was quite informative and this should be used if he precisely knows f(x,y) and I wonder if there are other methods

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak: best method to implement in a computer, so, better, the fastest.